# Derivation of XML data types

Tags: xml, xsd, spring-ws

I have an XSD file, where I reference a datatype called STE_Paket:

```
<xsd:element name="Paket" type="dt:STE_Paket" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

Datatype STE_Paket is an abstract type:

```
<xsd:complexType name="STE_Paket" abstract="true">
  <xsd:simpleContent>
    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

In my Project I created now an extension of STE_Paket in my own namespace and with an enumeration:

```
    <xsd:complexType name="STE_MyPaket">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="dt:STE_Paket">
                <xsd:enumeration value="value1" />
                <xsd:enumeration value="value2" />
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

I try to use this schemas in a spring-ws SOAP Webservice and I specify the datatype:

```
<pm:Paket xsi:type="my-dt:STE_MyPaket">value1</pm:Paket>
```

But when I try to execute the request it always tries to create an object of STE_Paket and not STE_MyPaket. That fails, because STE_Paket is an abstract type.
Here is the full error message I receive in my Java project:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory - failed to create a new instance of class com.dpn.mapper.kr.STEPaket
```

The full stacktrace is that:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(ClassFactory.java:132)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create(ClassFactory.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:688)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl$TransducerImpl.parse(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:388)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.TextLoader.text(TextLoader.java:69)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:590)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.text(InterningXmlVisitor.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.processText(SAXConnector.java:213)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:127)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:369)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:352)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor$Jaxb2SourceCallback.domSource(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TraxUtils.doWithSource(TraxUtils.java:82)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.unmarshalFromRequestPayload(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.getMethodArguments(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:314)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:279)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:230)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:174)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:288)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: A couple of edits are required in your question. In your XML snippet the xsi:type attribute looks wrong. I think you meant to say xsi:type="my-dt:STE_MyPaket". Also, you should quote the exact text of the error message(s) that you are receiving.

Comment: Thanks for your hints! I have corrected everything.